# Is there a way to get the CRM connection from IServiceProvider in a Dynamics CRM Plugin?

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Seems silly that a plugin is registered within the CRM with handlers kicked off from events that have fired, and yet at the same time the Service Provider doesn't give direct access to a Connection context. Instead, everything I've read says I have to re-create my own separate CrmConnection to use. Is there a way to get access to a type via the GetService() method?

So, when using an early-bound class with a ServiceContext name of "XrmServiceContext", instead of the following:

```
// "Xrm" is a config file node with applicable creds.
using ( var context = new XrmServiceContext( new CrmConnection( "Xrm" ) ) )
{
...
}
```

I'd love to do something like this:

```
public void Execute( IServiceProvider serviceProvider )
{
    var context = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(CrmConnection));
...
}
```

Is there anything like this out there? Or maybe a better way than using a node in the config file?

Answer (score 1):

This is the basic Execute implementation.
service can be used to interact with CRM.

```
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
        IOrganizationServiceFactory factory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
        IOrganizationService service = factory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

        if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
        {
            Entity target = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
        }
    }
```